# Download Email using Gmail Server , 'Authentication Failed'

Tags: java, download, email-attachments, gmail-api, pop3

I want to download Email using Gmail Server , for that firstly i need to connect with it , Am using Pop3 Gmail Server for this , but 'Authentication Failed' error occur. code for connection is :

```
        Properties properties = new Properties();
    // server setting
    properties.put("mail.pop3.host",host);
    properties.put("mail.pop3.port",port);
    // SSL setting
    properties.setProperty("mail.pop3.socketFactory.class",
            "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    properties.setProperty("mail.pop3.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
    properties.setProperty("mail.pop3.socketFactory.port",
            String.valueOf(port));
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);
    try {
        // connects to the message store
        Store store = session.getStore("pop3s");
        store.connect(userName, password);    //error at this line
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javamail and Gmail Pop3 SSL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10352718/javamail-and-gmail-pop3-ssl)

Comment: Maybe , bt this doesnot work @Kennet

Comment: Error : javax.mail.MessagingException: Connect failed;
  nested exception is:
 javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
 at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store.protocolConnect(POP3Store.java:213)
 at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:345)
 at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:226)
 at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:246)

Comment: Found this http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javamail_api/javamail_api_checking_emails.htm

Comment: Same problem , don't know why ," stor.connect(userName,password);" is not working

Answer (score 2):

The problem is due to security settings in Gmail, if you add

```
emailSession.setDebug(true);
```

you will actually get a link to the error message, https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754

Also found [this](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/OAuth2)

Answer (score 0):

Thankyou , bt it doesnot works , Issue was of Avast Antivirus , it was blocking to connect with mail server .